# How to clone my existing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that on my local development machine and I want to copy it and have a sort of starting point in case I don't want to start over from scratch later for future projects. Is there a rails command I can use to "clone" it or should I simply copy and paste the directory?

Comment: Why you don't use traditional `copy-paste` to taking a copy of your current project state? You just need to copy the whole project directory

Comment: You might want to look at [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) for creating your starter app. It's an open source project that generates a number of starter apps and it stays up-to-date with changes in Rails and gems.

Comment: I just did a copy-paste and I'll keep that guy on the side for now. I'll look into Rails Composer also. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rails command to clone your app. But you can install git on your system and create a git repo to do what you want easily. To do this go to your rails app root and execute

```
git init
git add .
git commmit -m "Your commit message"
```

You can then continue working and commit your changes as needed or discard all or individual changes. You can also clone your app with the `git clone` commmand.

Comment: I'm realizing what I'm looking for doesn't really exist. I already use git for version control and i'll continue to use it with this project. Thanks!